# TFS 2015 Get Back to Upgrade Wizard after Powershell Install

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

During the installation of TFS 2015 on a 2008 server, it prompted me that I needed to install a newer version of Powershell. Doing that required a restart, and now I can't figure out how to get back to the upgrade wizard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same thing but in my case got to the end and evidently my server needed rebooting (would be nice if it said that up front).

To get to the wizard:

1. Start TFS Admin console
2. Select the Application Tier node and then in the pane on the right select 'Configure Installed Features'
3. In the Configuration Center, left hand list, click the 'Upgrade' node.

Now you'll see a button on the lower right that says 'Start Wizard', which should get you back to where you were.

Comment: Hi, In the upgrade wizard the option to "upgrade" is not available (shown grayed). Probably due to an upgrade that was canceled/incomplete before. How can I restart the upgrade process anyway (Tfs 2012 DBs are in place).

Comment: Ok, found it :-). You can run "tfsconfig setup /uninstall:all" to remove all configured features and then run the wizard again.

Answer (score 5):

You can run `tfsmgmt.exe configure` to reopen the configuration wizard.

It should be located under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Tools\`